# Problem setting up auto-connect for Bluetooth headphones

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, support, blueman

I am a new lubuntu user first time installing lubuntu 20.4 on a windows 10 2gb ram and 32 HDD crappy laptop after clean installing as primary os everything seems to be working correctly except having a Bluetooth   auto-connect issue with the laptop.
I tried to search the forum for the answer but nothing seems to work to get my headphones to auto connect on startup. I tried solutions like blueman (pair and trust ) and editing the pulse audio config file for auto connect. The only way I can connect is either by terminal connect with my headphones mac address by bluetoothctl commands or blueman. Recent devices have to manually connect.

Please someone guide me and provide a non technical answer or easy to understand one that can help me fix this.  If u need any other information I can add it to this post.
Thanks